# Display a div as popup using Jquery on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am learning Jquery and came across this problem where I had to display div as popup on button click in the same window.Any suggestion on how to achieve this ?

Comment: see http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jquery ui dialog, or, if you want to get more ...fancy, you could use [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/home):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#inline").fancybox({
  'hideOnContentClick': true
 });
  
  
});
```

```css
.btn{
  border: 1px solid #006; 
  color:#01ACEE; 
  font: bold 16px Tahoma; 
  border-radius:7px; 
  padding:4px;
  
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/fancy/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/fancy/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/fancy/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/fancy/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>

<a id="inline" class="btn" href="#data">My Button</a>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="data">
    <img alt="" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8366/8483546751_86494ae914_m.jpg"><br>
        <h3>My Cool Title</h3>
        <p>Put your cool item descrtiption here</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [jquery ui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) like,

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

Also you can try [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)